# C++ Proprietary Definition 'unique_bool' and 'unique_ulong', type conversion back to 'bool' and 'ulong'

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c-preprocessor

I am trying to making a board-specific API (C++) more generic. I have access to their .h file. At the top of the header file, they "redfine" boolean and ulong types as such ('unique' replacing their proprietary name):

```
#ifndef UNIQUEDLLAPI
#define UNIQUEDLLAPI
#endif
#ifndef UNIQUEAPI
#define UNIQUEAPI
#endif

#define uniqueret_bool UNIQUEDLLAPI unsigned int UNIQUEAPI
#define uniqueret_ulong UNIQUEDLLAPI unsigned long UNIQUEAPI
```

**Could someone explain the syntax to me?** 
I know that the "definition" of this directive is: #define *identifier token-string-opt*, and it seems to do something similar to:

```
#define unsigned long ulong
```

so that it's easier typing. But I just don't understand the syntax that they wrote, as whoen above. How do the previous definitions (i.e. UNIQUEDLLAPI and UNIQUEAPI) come into play?

**Are there any issues with typecasting these types back to bool and ulong?** Can I just cast, for example:

```
uniqueret_bool a;
if ((bool) a) {...}
```

or would I have to do something else to make this work?

**Also, any suggestions to a better/more accurate title for question would be appreciated -- I don't really even know how to phrase it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not types, they are function declaration helpers, that annotate the function types with platform-specific goodies such as `__stdcall` and `__declspec(dllimport)` (with Microsoft compilers.  GCC has `__attribute__`).  There's no particular rhyme or reason controlling which of these go before the return type and which come after, the developer apparently chose to use a macro to encode that rather than memorizing the correct order.

Compare to Microsoft's similar macro, `STDMETHOD`:

```
#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE __stdcall
#define STDMETHOD(method) virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE method
```

Remember that macros are simple (but powerful) text-substitution, they are not just an archaic form of `typedef`.

To address your proposed usage, the answer is that you should not use these macros with variable declarations, only functions (maybe for function pointers).  To capture the return value from a call to such a function, use `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` as the type, not these macros.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the response. Could you confirm: since `uniqueret_bool` is just a function declaration helper/annotation, there should be no issue with treating it as a boolean (since it _is_ just a boolean). Is this correct?

Comment: If by "it" you mean the return value from calling such a function, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional definition are there to prevent compilation errors if the names are not previously defined. Potentially, this kind of structure can be used to have some modifiers on the variable types.

Consider what happens if `UNIQUEDLLAPI` is predefined (either from an earlier header, or using a command line option) to be equal to 'const'.
The flow would would SKIP the first `#ifndef` and leave `UNIQUEDLLAPI` as it is, and later the type definitions will be of const types.

Regarding the validity of casting, that depends on the actual usage of the 2 "decorating" defines.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want another datatype if UNIQUEAPI is defined mabe a unsigned long long instead of a unsigned long.

Bool is not available in ANSI C so a simple cast would not be possible here.